# What type of targets are valid for Scorching Ray?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting

Almost all the attack spells in the PHB specific the type of target as either a creature, an object, or a point in space (as per Target section on PHB pg 204).

[Scorching Ray](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/scorching-ray) just says

> You create three rays of fire and hurl them at targets within range

But it doesn't specify what types of targets (creature, object, point in space).  Should I interpret that to mean all three are then valid?  I couldn't find anything in the Errata or Sage Advice Compendium on this specifically.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Yes, all the listed targets are valid.

Many spells and other effects are examplary to the rule Specific Beats General on page 7 of the Player's Handbook:

> Remember this: If a specific rule contradicts a general rule, the specific rule wins.

The spell *scorching ray*, however, falls in line with the general rule, and seems to have no specific rules for the targets of its attacks. Since the spell does not clarify a specific target for its rays, we use the general rule about Making an Attack on page 193-194 of the *Player's Handbook* , more specifically the first bulletpoint:

> Pick a target within your attack's range: a creature, an object, or a location.

Answer (score 1):

Unless it says otherwise, you can target any creature or object within range (and not behind total cover).

As a general rule, attacks have broader targeting restrictions than save-inducing abilities.

Comment: Well, only creatures can make saving throws because objects and spatial points don't have ability scores. Saving throw spells/abilities are naturally limited in targeting scope because of this fact ;-)